# jQuery plugin function override from different file

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I want to override a function inside my JS library. I have following code structure

Plugin.js

```
function Plugin(elements, options) {
    'use strict';
    return this.init(elements, options);
}

if (typeof module === 'object') {
    module.exports = Plugin;
}

(function (window, document) {
    'use strict';       

    Plugin.prototype = {
        defaults: {
            showFlag: false,
            indent: true                         
        },

        insertDiv: function(parentElement){
           //some jquery code;
        },

        insertCustomData: function(parentElement){
           //some jquery code
           this.insertDiv(parentElement);
        },


    };

}(window, document));
```

test.html

```
<html>
<body>
  <div id="test"> 
    <p>Test Content</p>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="plugin.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript">    
    var plugin = new Plugin('test', {showFlag: true, indent:false});                    
</script>
</html>
```

I want to override insertDiv() function present in plugin.js and provide my own implementation of insertDiv() in my test.html

So when I call insertDiv() from insertCustomData() it should execute the function in my test.html and not in plugin.js

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just overwrite it

```
<html>
<body>
  <div id="test"> 
    <p>Test Content</p>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="plugin.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript">    

    Plugin.prototype.insertDiv = function() {
        // something else ?
    }

    var plugin = new Plugin('test', {showFlag: true, indent:false});                    
</script>
</html>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/r9uy57c8/)